# query elements in an array by field name c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an array of two rows ,each row looks like this with variation in data.
[image]

Now I want to fetch the `FieldValue` of the row where `FieldName="LinkedIn Profil"`
Is there any way to achieve this through linq?..Pardon me if I said any thing stupid..as a m newbie to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var l = yourArray.Where(r => r.FieldName == "LinkedIn Profil").Select(m => m.FieldValue).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
var newList = currentList
                  .Where(x => x.FieldName = "LinkedIn Profil")
                  .Select(x => x.FieldValue);
```

This will give you a list of strings with that field value.. I assume that's what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from item in MyAarray
                 where (item.FieldName == "LinkedIn Profil")
                 select item;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to achieve this through linq

Sure, you could filter and project the collection:

```
string result = list
    .Where(x => x.FieldName == "LinkedIn Profile")
    .Select(x => x.FieldValue)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return the first element that satisfies the filter. If you don't call FirstOrDefault you will get a list of all rows that satisfy the condition.